# error: Unable to initialize the encoder: Transport library initialization error

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs, ld, aac

I'm trying to run an audio encoder using ffmpeg command but when I try to encode in aac_ld codec or aac_eld codec, it gives me an error stating that...

```
[libfdk_aac @ 0x1e20770] Unable to initialize the encoder: Transport library initialization error
```

but for other codecs it's running perfectly fine.

I'm using this command for aac_eld codec

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_eld -b:a 320k -r:a 48000 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.60:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

and getting this output

```
    ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1505822120.258801, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
[libfdk_aac @ 0x1e20770] Unable to initialize the encoder: Transport library initialization error
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://192.168.1.60:1234?pkt_size=1316':
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[1]+  Killed                  ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 320k -r:a 48000 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.60:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

but for another codec like aac_low it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me so I made a bug report although I was unclear if the problem is with `ffmpeg` or libfdk itself. [#6683 Transport library initialization error in libfdk_aac when using aac_eld profile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6683).

Comment: yes I too think so because it's been mentioned in the ffmpeg-codecs man page that it will work like this only

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution for my question. Apparently mpegts is not the correct output format to encode audio in aac_ld or aac_eld. I replaced mpegts with nut.

```
ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i hw:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_eld -b:a 320k -r:a 48000 -f nut udp://192.168.1.60:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

but this format can only be decoded using ffplay.